# Library or language extension to provide traits in Java?

Tags: java, traits

I've just been introduced to traits ("traits" in Smalltalk, "roles" in Perl). I'd like to experiment with them quickly, in a language I'm familiar with. Are there any libraries or extensions in Java that support traits?

I've heard that AspectJ and Qi4J both support mixins, but I've also read that mixins are different from traits. So can I also use one of those libraries for traits?

Or how about Scala, that's fully backward compatible with Java, right? Does that support traits?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or how about Scala, that's fully backward compatible with Java, right? Does that support traits?

Yes, Scala has [full support for Traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126). It has to jump through a few weird hoops to make it work with the JVM, but it's there, and it's very powerful.

You can write your experiment in Scala, and it'll interop with your existing Java stuff (tools depending)

Answer (score 2):

Qi4j 2.0 (in the works) adds strong Scala support, and we are working on making Scala Traits useful as Qi4j mixins and concerns (AOP "around advice" equivalents).
The Scala trait compiles down to static methods that takes a proxy instance of the owning class as the first argument (classic C++ representation in C). Qi4j will be able to wire up the the Trait as a Mixin (i.e. the methods can be exposed in the Composite's public interface) and bind in the underlying StateHolder for the composite to be used by the Trait, so it seems that traits will have state...

FTR; Qi4j 2.0 is also minimizing the type footprint, allowing for Qi4j-agnostic types to be used even more than before.